# Why the scatter plot is plotting zero data points when the data has no zero values

Tags: python, scatter-plot, axis

I want to plot a scatter plot between ambienttemp and lightintensity. Based on the distribution for light intensity, there is no zero values, the min value is 10.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f4vl.png)

But my scatter plot is plotting zero or values less than zero
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o65R.png)

Here is my code

```
xs = df_combinedAL['AmbientTemp'].values
ys = df_combinedAL['LightIntensity'].values 
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
plt.scatter(xs,ys,alpha=0.6)
plt.xlabel('AmbientTemp')
plt.ylabel('LightIntensity')
plt.title('Relationship between LightIntensity and AmbientTemp')
```

Thanks in advance if someone can answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not plotting below 0. It just looks like it as a big circle is used to represent the point. Additionally, your scale for the y-axis is giant, so your minimum value, which is `10` basically looks like it's on `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a scale problem. The plot contains 10.000 points and it actually seems that there are points in 0 because the dimensions of the points is bigger than the scale of the axis, but if you zoom in you can note that there are no points in 0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).